# exact form of the integral of x^(-x) between 0 and infinity

Tags: integration

I have searched the internet for an exact answer and although I have found many decimal approximations, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E(-x)+from+0+to+infinity I have not been able to find an exact form.

Comment: I doubt that there's a closed form.  For $\int_0^1 x^{-x} \, dx$
there's the memorable formual $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}$
[proof sketch: write $x^{-x} = \exp(-x\log x)$, use 
$e^t = \sum_{m=0}^\infty t^m/m!$, and integrate termwise];
but that's not really a closed form either.